# How to reindex a pandas pivot table

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I created a pivot table which grouped by according to one of the columns and the month of the time index.

This is the pivot table

```
                    AWRT       AWFT       AWDT
Time     type                                 
April    All   38.190119  65.789103  27.598984
         DHW   19.676627  60.889196  41.212569
         SH    47.342757  61.335566  13.992809
February All   43.896487  57.982944  14.086457
         SH    40.864670  50.567133   9.702463
March    All   42.083836  69.139818  27.055982
         DHW   18.908873  62.936898  44.028024
         SH    52.249342  70.013904  17.764563
```

Now I would like february march and april to appear in chronological, not alphabetical order

trying to reindex this way:

```
new_index=[['February', 'March', 'April'], ['All', 'DHW', 'SH']]
df1=df1.reindex(new_index)
```

I obtain the following, which is not a pivot table anymore:

```
        AWRT       AWFT       AWDT
Time     type                                 
February All   43.896487  57.982944  14.086457
March    DHW   18.908873  62.936898  44.028024
April    SH    47.342757  61.335566  13.992809
```

I also tried to directly access the labels of the pivot table index but I am told these are immutable.

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reindex *only* the relevant level (`level=0`):

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['April', 'February', 'March'], ['All', 'DHW', 'SH']],
                    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
                    names=['Time', 'type'])
df = pd.DataFrame([[38.190119, 65.789103, 27.598984],
                   [19.676627, 60.889196, 41.212569],
                   [47.342757, 61.335566, 13.992809],
                   [43.896487, 57.982944, 14.086457],
                   [40.864670, 50.567133, 9.702463],
                   [42.083836, 69.139818, 27.055982],
                   [18.908873, 62.936898, 44.028024],
                   [52.249342, 70.013904, 17.764563]],
                  columns=['AWRT', 'AWFT', 'AWDT'],
                  index=idx)

print(df)

#                     AWRT       AWFT       AWDT
# Time     type                                 
# April    All   38.190119  65.789103  27.598984
#          DHW   19.676627  60.889196  41.212569
#          SH    47.342757  61.335566  13.992809
# February All   43.896487  57.982944  14.086457
#          SH    40.864670  50.567133   9.702463
# March    All   42.083836  69.139818  27.055982
#          DHW   18.908873  62.936898  44.028024
#          SH    52.249342  70.013904  17.764563

print(df.reindex(['February', 'March', 'April'], level=0))

#                     AWRT       AWFT       AWDT
# Time     type                                 
# February All   43.896487  57.982944  14.086457
#          SH    40.864670  50.567133   9.702463
# March    All   42.083836  69.139818  27.055982
#          DHW   18.908873  62.936898  44.028024
#          SH    52.249342  70.013904  17.764563
# April    All   38.190119  65.789103  27.598984
#          DHW   19.676627  60.889196  41.212569
#          SH    47.342757  61.335566  13.992809
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a multi-index in order to re-index properly:

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['February', 'March', 'April'], ['All', 'DHW', 'SH']], 
    names=['Time', 'type']
)
df1.reindex(new_index)
```

Ideally you'd use a categorical multi-index, but I don't know if that's possible.