# Create empty dataframe based on 2 lists (representing the row and column), then fill in based on values from another dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance, index-match

Sample Data:

| id | start_to_end_date | attribute | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1395287 | 2019-01-01 - 2019-12-31 | CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 49.369 |
| 1395288 | 2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31 | CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 75.476 |
| 1395289 | 2020-04-01 - 2020-06-30 | CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 17.69 |
| 1395290 | 2020-07-01 - 2020-09-30 | CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 19.056 |
| 1395291 | 2021-01-01 - 2021-12-31 | CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 137.292 |

If some of you are familiar with financial statements and Index Match in Excel, I would basically like to recreate what an Income Statement looks like.

I have all my unique column_names in a list. This current order is important:

```
column_names = ['2020-04-01 - 2020-06-30',
 '2020-07-01 - 2020-09-30',
 '2021-01-01 - 2021-03-31',
 '2021-04-01 - 2021-06-30',
 '2021-07-01 - 2021-09-30',
 '2022-01-01 - 2022-03-31',
 '2019-01-01 - 2019-12-31',
 '2020-01-01 - 2020-12-31',
 '2021-01-01 - 2021-12-31']
```

I also have all my unique row names in a list. This current order is important:

```
row_names = ['RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax',
 'CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold',
 'GrossProfit',
 'ResearchAndDevelopmentExpense']
```

The final dataframe would have the above `column_names` going across, the above `row_names` going down (as the index).
The values that would fill in dataframe would be from `df['val']`, retrieved by matching `df['attribute'] == column_names[i]` and `df['start_to_end_date'] == row_names[i]`.

How would I do this?

- I tried to create an empty Dataframe first with the 2 lists but there is no place to query for `df['val']`:

`pd.DataFrame(row_names , columns=column_names, index=[i[0] for i in row_names ])`

- I'm imagining something in the end would look like:

`df_new = np.where((df['attribute'] == column_names) & (df['start_to_end_date'] == row_names), df['val'], None)`.

Ideal End result:

|  | 2020-04-01 - 2020-06-30 | 2020-07-01 - 2020-09-30 | 2021-01-01 - 2021-03-31 | 2021-04-01 - 2021-06-30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax | ##.## from df[val] | ##.## | ##.## | ##.## |
| CostOfGoodsAndServicesSold | 17.69 | 19.056 | ##.## | ##.## |
| GrossProfit | ##.## from df[val] | ##.## | ##.## | ##.## |

Comment: `pivot`, then reindex with `row_names` to ensure having the desired order

Comment: Thank you. Just in case others had the same question here is the answer:

# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe
# Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845059/how-to-reindex-a-pandas-pivot-table
index_match_df = df_new.pivot_table(
        values='val', index='attribute', columns='start_to_end_date',
        fill_value=0)
index_match_df = index_match_df.reindex(y_axis_titles)
index_match_df